# update query copy source to destination table access 2010

Tags: sql, ms-access

just trying to figure out how to do the following:

I have a 2 tables (`tbl_WBint`: destination and `temp_Agtpinwb` : source) and need to use update query to copy over fields in `tbl_WBint`.  The issue is initially I used a query to initialize all columns in `tbl_WBint` with `0` before applying update query.  After I use the below SQL update query it replaces some rows with fields from `temp_Agtpinwb` table, which is what I am looking to do but the other rows that had zero during initialize query are blanks.  Is there a way to only run update query if the source table has entries that need to be updated to the destination table while keeping other values in destination table as `0` still?

Hope that makes sense.

```
UPDATE tbl_WBint 
INNER JOIN temp_Agtpinwb 
    ON tbl_WBint.[Agent Pin] = temp_Agtpinwb.[Agent Pin]
SET 
    tbl_WBint.[Agent Pin] = [temp_Agtpinwb]![Agent Pin], 
    tbl_WBint.[WB Current] = [temp_Agtpinwb]![WB Current], 
    tbl_WBint.[WB Prior Year] = [temp_Agtpinwb]![WB Prior Year],
    tbl_WBint.[WB Prior Year 3] = [temp_Agtpinwb]![WB Prior Year 3],
    tbl_WBint.[WB Jan Count] = [temp_Agtpinwb]![WB Jan Count], 
    tbl_WBint.[WB Feb Count] = [temp_Agtpinwb]![WB Feb Count],
    tbl_WBint.[WB Mar Count] = [temp_Agtpinwb]![WB Mar Count], 
    tbl_WBint.[WB Apr Count] = [temp_Agtpinwb]![WB Apr Count], 
    tbl_WBint.[WB May Count] = [temp_Agtpinwb]![WB May Count],
    tbl_WBint.[WB Jun Count] = [temp_Agtpinwb]![WB Jun Count], 
    tbl_WBint.[WB Jul Count] = [temp_Agtpinwb]![WB Jul Count], 
    tbl_WBint.[WB Aug Count] = [temp_Agtpinwb]![WB Aug Count], 
    tbl_WBint.[WB Sep Count] = [temp_Agtpinwb]![WB Sep Count],
    tbl_WBint.[WB Oct Count] = [temp_Agtpinwb]![WB Oct Count],
    tbl_WBint.[WB Nov Count] = [temp_Agtpinwb]![WB Nov Count], 
    tbl_WBint.[WB Dec Count] = [temp_Agtpinwb]![WB Dec Count];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like some of the values from temp_Agtpinwb are null values and are over-writing your 0'd values, you could use

```
UPDATE tbl_WBint 
INNER JOIN temp_Agtpinwb 
    ON tbl_WBint.[Agent Pin] = temp_Agtpinwb.[Agent Pin]
SET 
    tbl_WBint.[Agent Pin] = [temp_Agtpinwb]![Agent Pin], 
    tbl_WBint.[WB Current] = Nz([temp_Agtpinwb]![WB Current],0), 
    tbl_WBint.[WB Prior Year] = Nz([temp_Agtpinwb]![WB Prior Year],0),
    tbl_WBint.[WB Prior Year 3] = Nz([temp_Agtpinwb]![WB Prior Year 3],0),
    tbl_WBint.[WB Jan Count] = Nz([temp_Agtpinwb]![WB Jan Count],0), 
    tbl_WBint.[WB Feb Count] = Nz([temp_Agtpinwb]![WB Feb Count],0),
    tbl_WBint.[WB Mar Count] = Nz([temp_Agtpinwb]![WB Mar Count],0), 
    tbl_WBint.[WB Apr Count] = Nz([temp_Agtpinwb]![WB Apr Count],0), 
    tbl_WBint.[WB May Count] = Nz([temp_Agtpinwb]![WB May Count],0),
    tbl_WBint.[WB Jun Count] = Nz([temp_Agtpinwb]![WB Jun Count],0), 
    tbl_WBint.[WB Jul Count] = Nz([temp_Agtpinwb]![WB Jul Count],0), 
    tbl_WBint.[WB Aug Count] = Nz([temp_Agtpinwb]![WB Aug Count],0), 
    tbl_WBint.[WB Sep Count] = Nz([temp_Agtpinwb]![WB Sep Count],0),
    tbl_WBint.[WB Oct Count] = Nz([temp_Agtpinwb]![WB Oct Count],0),
    tbl_WBint.[WB Nov Count] = Nz([temp_Agtpinwb]![WB Nov Count],0), 
    tbl_WBint.[WB Dec Count] = Nz([temp_Agtpinwb]![WB Dec Count],0);
```

NZ will replace your null values with zeroes.
If this is the case, I believe you wouldn't need the "initializing query" either.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use conditional logic with [`IIF()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/iif-function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3) to check for `NULL` and either keep original value or update with source value. And consider using table aliases as shown below to cut down on long table names.

```
UPDATE tbl_WBint w
INNER JOIN temp_Agtpinwb a
    ON w.[Agent Pin] = a.[Agent Pin]
SET 
    w.[Agent Pin] = IIF(a.[Agent Pin] IS NULL, w.[Agent Pin], a.[Agent Pin]), 
    w.[WB Current] = IIF(a.[WB Current] IS NULL, w.[WB Current], a.[WB Current]), 
    w.[WB Prior Year] = IIF(a.[WB Prior Year] IS NULL, w.[WB Prior Year], a.[WB Prior Year]),
    ...
```

Comment: Is it possible to have a message box after an AutoExec macro is run to display the number of records?  I have 2 macros inside AutoExec macro (1 for building my tables and 2nd one for building a table to count total number of records).  I know this is possible with a form but I want to create the access database so it automatically runs when you double-click on it.

Comment: Ill post it in another thread if I don't find answer on other posts.